# stop and restart node.js server from another server

Tags: node.js, express

I have two server running in node.js. A main server and a maintenance server. Is there a possibility to stop/start the main server out of the maintenance server? Both running on the same system. At the moment, I start both manually via the package.json.

Happy for some help!

Comment: are you using Express.js?

Comment: Yes, i do use Express.js